# portable battery packs for decorative lights

Tags: home-experiment

I a set of home decorative lights that is powered by a portable 2 x D cell batteries. Can I replace the current pack with a new pack that takes AA batteries

Comment: Only if you supply the same voltage and current that would have been provided by the two D-cell batteries, though I am not sure how or why you would do this...

Comment: For the same number of batteries the lights will only last for about a quarter of the time... if you don't mind that. Alternatively, you can use four times as many batteries, although it's not good practice to connect batteries in parallel.

Comment: @CuriousOne it *can* be good practice, provided the person is a firefighter (or pyromancer).

Comment: @Asher: Interesting... and that is how they store them in their equipment or they just connect before use?

Comment: @CuriousOne I mean that connecting batteries in parallel can afford them practice in fighting fires :)

Comment: @Asher: D'ow! My humor detector is broken, today! :-)